# react-stripe-elements not detecting Stripe.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a weird problem with `react-stripe-elements`. The module is crashing with an uncaught error which reads as follows:

```
Uncaught Error: Please load Stripe.js (https://js.stripe.com/v3/) on this page to use react-stripe-elements.
    at new Provider (Provider.js:38)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:294
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:293)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:279)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:187)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:522)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:522)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:121)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:206)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:310)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:297)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateDOMChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:942)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:760)
    at ReactDOMComponent.receiveComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:722)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:124)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:753)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:723)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:644)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:546)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:124)
    at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:109)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:206)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:310)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:297)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateDOMChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:942)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:760)
    at ReactDOMComponent.receiveComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:722)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:124)
    at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:109)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:206)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:310)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:297)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateDOMChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:942)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:760)
    at ReactDOMComponent.receiveComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:722)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:124)
```

The module seems to think that `Stripe.js` is not loaded. However, I have confirmed the following to be in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

This is consistent with the instructions provided by stripe [here](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements).

If I refresh the page, it loads fine without throwing an error!

The situation seems so simple that I'm not even sure what avenue to take to debug it. Stripe js should be present, and it is, but it isn't detected. Has anyone experienced this problem or have any idea how to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone comes across similar behavior, this problem resulted from an unstable internet connection. It turned out that the connection with stripe was more unstable than connections with anything else, and the `stripe.js` library wasn't being downloaded properly. This is why it was asking me to `Please load stripe.js`.

Comment: any solution or just a fact of life?

Comment: The solution was to stabilize my internet connection.

Comment: I guess you have to lookout for the error and catch it so the app doesn't crash? Or do you just hope it never happens to real users?

Comment: I guess if you are worried real users are going to see it you could catch it and display a modal along the lines of "Having trouble connecting to Stripe, your internet connection may be unstable."

Answer (score 1):

Create a function which returns Promise to load stripe.js and use React `Hooks(useState, useEffect)` to trigger actions to show React Stripe Elements when Stripe script loaded.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react
import {
  StripeProvider,
  Elements,
  CardNumberElement
} from 'react-stripe-elements'

const loadScript = src =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve({ successful: true })
    })
    script.addEventListener('error', event => {
      reject({ error: event })
    })
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  })

const MyComponent = () => {
 const [stripeLoaded, setStripeLoaded] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await loadScript('https://js.stripe.com/v3/')
      setStripeLoaded(result)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 

  return  stripeLoaded.successful ? (
    <StripeProvider>
      <Elements>
        <CardNumberElement />
      </Elements>
    </StripeProvider>) : null
}
```

Comment: I plugged this in as it seems likely to fix my issue. However, I now get TypeError: TypeError: (0, _react.useState)({})','(0, _react.useState)' is undefined. In both the screen and the component, i have import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react' as the first line. -- Please advise.

Comment: @Taersious that seems like an issue with the version of React you are using. Try updating to at least version 16.8 (the one with Hooks: https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html)